# VueJS: Why does this.$set() throw error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the `$set` method to let Vue know that the object has changed and it keeps throwing the following error. Am I misusing the method?

**Error**

```
TypeError: exp.trim is not a function. (In 'exp.trim()', 'exp.trim' is undefined)
```

**Context**

```
<template>
<div class="panel-heading" @click="expandAction(action, $index)">
  <div class="panel-title">
    <span>{{ action.display }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" v-show="action.expanded">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
<template>

<script>
expandAction: function (action, index) {
  this.collapseActions();

  // Works, but Vue doesn't detect change
  // action.expanded = true;

  // Throws error
  this.$set(this.$data.actionRepository, `actions[${index}].expanded`, true);
},
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For Vue 1.x:

Following clarification from @Donnie it is important to highlight that the behaviour of this.$set has changed between Vue 1 & Vue 2.

In Vue 1 this.$set expects to update a data param on the component you are calling it within, whereas in Vue 2 it is an alias of Vue.set.

Therefore to achieve this in Vue 1 you would either call `Vue.set`:

```
Vue.set(this.actionRepository.actions[index], 'expanded', true)
```

http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#Vue-set

or

```
this.$set(`actionRepository.actions[${index}].expanded`, true)
```

http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#vm-set

### For Vue 2:

```
this.$set(this.actionRepository.actions[index], 'expanded', true)
```

that said you only really need to use `$set` if you are creating a new param of `expanded`. If it already exists you can just:

```
this.actionRepository.actions[index].expanded = true
```

---

If you have the action object passed to the method then you could also use:

```
this.$set(action, 'expanded', true)
```

---

Comment: Option 1 gives me the same error as above. Option 2 works, but Vue doesn't detect the change. The values are updated correctly according to the console, though.

Comment: I have tried `action.expanded = true;` as the most straightforward option, but Vue detection is still the issue.

Comment: are you using vue 2?

Comment: I added a little more to the answer as it seems like you may be accessing a different object within the template (action) to the expandAction's  this.actionRepository.action[index] ... object

Comment: I get the same error which is baffling since I am using a similar statement in another component. I'm using Vue 1.0.21.

Comment: According to the documentation, it looks like it should be `this.$set('action.expanded', true);`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I've updated the answer - use Vue.set for consistency with vue 2